# AttributeError: module 'fsspec.callbacks' has no attribute 'TqdmCallback'

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, dataset, lotus-domino, huggingface

I am trying to import datasets. I have already installed with pip and I am still getting this error. I am running this code on Domino which should be a controlled environment. Is there something I need to do to adjust the environment?

```
pip install datasets --upgrade
pip install datasets --user
```

Error I'm getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 1
----> 1 from datasets import Dataset
      2 train_dataset = Dataset.from_dict({"question": list(train_q), "label": train_label})
      3 train_dataset

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/__init__.py:22
      1 # flake8: noqa
      2 # Copyright 2020 The HuggingFace Datasets Authors and the TensorFlow Datasets Authors.
      3 #
   (...)
     17 # pylint: enable=line-too-long
     18 # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top,g-bad-import-order,wrong-import-position
     20 __version__ = "2.14.4"
---> 22 from .arrow_dataset import Dataset
     23 from .arrow_reader import ReadInstruction
     24 from .builder import ArrowBasedBuilder, BeamBasedBuilder, BuilderConfig, DatasetBuilder, GeneratorBasedBuilder

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py:66
     63 from requests import HTTPError
     65 from . import config
---> 66 from .arrow_reader import ArrowReader
     67 from .arrow_writer import ArrowWriter, OptimizedTypedSequence
     68 from .data_files import sanitize_patterns

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/arrow_reader.py:34
     32 from .table import InMemoryTable, MemoryMappedTable, Table, concat_tables
     33 from .utils import logging
---> 34 from .utils.file_utils import cached_path
     37 if TYPE_CHECKING:
     38     from .info import DatasetInfo  # noqa: F401

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/utils/file_utils.py:348
    344         raise ValueError(f"HEAD can be called with at most one path but was called with {paths}")
    345     return fs.info(paths[0])
--> 348 class TqdmCallback(fsspec.callbacks.TqdmCallback):
    349     def __init__(self, tqdm_kwargs=None, *args, **kwargs):
    350         super().__init__(tqdm_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)

AttributeError: module 'fsspec.callbacks' has no attribute 'TqdmCallback'
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading worked for me.
!pip install --upgrade fsspec